# Userform Command Button label

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Is there a way to make the vba label for a command button from a cell reference. For example if I create a new command button on a userform the label in the sub routine is CommandButton1. Can I make the 1 a cell value like CommandButton & (Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value) .visible = true?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Controls.Item(CommandButton & ws.Range("A1").Value).Visible = True    With this I got a run-time error -214702489 (80070057) could not find the specified object. The other is what is in the question.

Comment: Maybe you mean `CommandButton.Caption = WorkSheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value` ? It's difficult to understand what you are trying to do, even with your description. Is the name of your button `CommandButton`?

Comment: Not the caption, I understand how to change that dynamically. I'm talking about the subroutine. Private Sub CommandButton11_Click(). In my code if 2 numbers don't match I want to hid the command buttons that were pressed to display the numbers under. 
If ws.Range("Q1").Value = Range("Q2").Value Then
    ws.Range("S1").Value = ws.Range("Q1").Value
Else
    Controls.Item(CommandButton & ws.Range("R1").Value).Visible = True
    Controls.Item(CommandButton & ws.Range("R2").Value).Visible = True
End If

Comment: As I first stated, please include your code in your question, not in a comment. Code cannot be properly formatted in a comment. You can edit your question and add to it.

Comment: If you are trying to reference a control by name, but construct the name dynamically at run-time, you can use the form's `Controls` collection.

Comment: Something like `Me.Controls("CommandButton" & WorkSheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value).Caption = "Test"` ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this sub.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.CommandButton1.Caption = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
End Sub
```